# Javascript Validation - Letters and Space

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Good day. I'm very new to Javascript. I have this expression: `var firstname = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;` to validate first name in a form. However, this code only allows the user to input a single name without any space. How about if the user has two or more given first name?

I would like to know how to validate letters and space. I have searched similar questions here in Stackoverflow, but none of the answers worked for me.

I have tried these codes which I have found here: `/^[A-Za-z ]$/` or this one `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/` but these didn't work. Still, whenever I input two names in the First Name field, my alert message prompts me that I have entered an invalid character.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your entire code or at least the concrete code were you use your regular expression?

Comment: Here it is: `function lettersOnly(elem, helperMsg) { var firstname = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; if(elem.value.match(firstname)){return true;} else{alert(helperMsg); elem.focus(); return false;} } `

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with each one that you posted for what you want:

- `var firstname = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;` should be `var firstname = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;` (*added space*)
- `/^[A-Za-z ]$/` should be `/^[A-Za-z ]+$/` (*added `+`*)
- `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/` is a problem because I assume from the other examples that you want at least one letter, so it should be `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/` (*replaced `*` with `+`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried to replace the value with your suggested codes, but still, it prompts me that I have entered an invalid character.

Comment: That's because the rest of your code is invalid.  You never define `fn`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You may have seen my reply to clenfort. I've just forgotten to edit the "fn" to "firstname" here so that it'll be more understandable. Anyways, my orig code is `function lettersOnly(elem, helperMsg)
{
var fn =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(fn)){return true;}
else{alert(helperMsg); elem.focus(); return false;}
}` and I have tried your suggested methods, but they didn't work. But thank you for your help.

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cMDbb/  Try any of the function calls that are commented out and they work as expected. (Of course, I removed the `.value` part for easier demonstration)

Comment: Thank you sir. I just tried them all again. Maybe there are other problems in my entire code which why it didn't work. But I couldn't spot the mistake. I'm making my homework on making a simple online registration form.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, if the answer works, you may want to accept it so that future viewers can see that it is a good answer.

Comment: Hi sir. My code is already working with your suggested methods. I changed the file type of my HTML to .html instead of .htm only. I know they're the same. But when I changed the file type, it worked.